# header back to profile page after filling in form

Tags: php

Ok, so I was wondering having stuff saying congratulations you have done this. And stuff like that after someone has filled in a form is good to have but you don't always want that to happen, well I do not anyway for this form.

So basically instead of it echoing out what I have chosen too I would like it to header someone back to a page when everything has gone fine. I have tested my form and it all works fine. I tested it using echo but now I know it is working I would not like it to echo someone a message i would like it to header them back to there users page.

```
{
    $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET youtube='$youtube' WHERE username='$log_username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
    $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET twitch='$twitch' WHERE username='$log_username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli);
    $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET videotype='$videotype' WHERE username='$log_username'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli);
    echo "Video feeds update"; 
    exit();     
}
```

where is says `echo` just before `exit();` I would like it to header them back to there page or even any page I wish to in the future. Is it possible to do this and if it is what code would I use. I have tried using the normal header code but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know the code that is needed to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You could achieve this in the action="" attribute of the form, or as @Becs Carter has answered.

Comment: Which error do you get when you use header()?

Comment: it is fine now. I got an error about something already calling for a header or something like that. all seems to be fine now. Thank you for your response anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Location: url-in-here');
```